# Knowing about copy constructor in java

Tags: java, copy, copy-constructor

As we know java does not support call by reference and also it's true that if with copy constructor we use call by value then the copy constructor would call itself recursively    infinite times.Then how copy constructor do work in java??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What copy constructor?

Comment: Because the value that is passed is the value of the reference. The instance isn't copied every time.

Comment: @4castle Copy constructor:-used to make a copy of one class object from another class object of the same class type

Comment: Yes, but why would it call itself recursively? Copy constructors don't call other constructors.

Comment: @sagg1295 constructors are never implicitly invoked in Java. A copy constructor is only invoked if you write `new MyClass(instanceOfMyClass)` explicitly (reflection aside).

Comment: The `super()` constructor is the only constructor that ever gets invoked implicitly.

Comment: `Java does not support call by reference` - quite the opposite, for objects Java _only_ supports call-by-reference (on the other hand for primitive values only call-by-value is supported)

Comment: @Thomas I think this is confused with pass by value.  Java only passes by value, Java only has primitive and reference variable types and it passes references and primitives by value.

Comment: @Thomas This is a semantic discussion. The value of an object is its reference. Java is only pass-by-value.

Comment: Hmm, I have the feeling that this adds to the confusion, especially since the OP mixes call-by-reference and call-by-value. Since Java uses call-by-reference for objects there won't be any copy constructor involved and each manually called copy constructor would use call-by-reference as well so there can't be any infinite recursion.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm not saying anything about impliciltly invoking in java.I know that to use copy constructor i have to write it explicilty in my source code.I'm just asking how it works as in c++ we use call by reference than call by value as it goes into infinte recursiveness ,in java call by reference is not supported than how does copy consturctor work in java

Comment: `the value of an object is its reference.` - no, the value of a reference is the reference to that object. The value of an object would be its contents. As an example in `String s = new String("reference me");` `s` would be a reference to the string being created. If you do `String s2 = s;` you create another reference which points to the same object and you don't do any object construction.

Comment: @4castle  :please see my this code of copy constructor:class Copy
{
 int x,y;
 Copy(int x,int y)
 {
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
 }
 void show()
 {
  System.out.println(x);
  System.out.println(y);
 }
    Copy(Copy z)
 {
  this.x=z.x;
  this.y=z.y;
 }
 public static void main(String... s)
 {
  Copy c1=new Copy(10,20);
  c1.show();
  Copy c2=new Copy(c1);
  c2.show();
 }
}

Comment: @Thomas Of course, it's just that in Java the object and the reference are indistinguishable. We both said the same thing. In C your description would make more sense.

Comment: @sagg1295 to pick up your example I'll expand mine: `String copy = new String(s);`. This will do several things: 1) it will pass the reference `s` to the constructor which 2) will create a new `String` instance that now has the same value as the object referenced by `s` and 3) `copy` will now be assigned the reference to that new string, i.e. it will now "point" to the corresponding heap location.

Comment: @4castle you're right that when talking about objects you could use reference as a synonym (although it still would not be a perfect match). But in terms of call-by-value and call-by-reference there's a difference, especially if someone brings C++ and the like into the discussion (in C++ you could get a reference to an `int`, for example).

Comment: @sagg1295 As you can see there's a lot of discussion and misunderstanding of what you're talking about. If you still need clarification I'd suggest you add an example in both C++ (with call-by-value and call-by-reference to make a point) and Java (how you'd replicate the C++ example there). Then it might become clearer of what you're refering to (I guess you mean something like `Copy(Copy c)` vs. `Copy(Copy& c)` in C++).

Comment: @Thomas,Yes u correctly understands my problem,this was my question.

Comment: @sagg1295 then _please_ add those examples.

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent to a copy constructor in Java is overriding the `clone()` method of the `Object` class. The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) do a fairly good job at explaining its usage.

Comment: Another form of "copy constructor" would be something like `MyClass(MyClass source) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

> if with copy constructor we use call by value

There is no copy constructor built-in to Java. You can create one of your own but this is only used when you explicitly call it. To Java it is just another constructor which has no special meaning.

Java only has primitive and reference variable and when these are copied, no method or constructor is called.

e.g. In this example, it is the reference which is copied, not the object.

```
Integer i = 5; // A *reference* to an Integer object.
Integer i = j; // A *reference* to the same object.
```

> copy constructor would call itself recursively infinite times.

A common misconception is that Java has Object variable types when it doesn't.

Comment: ,according to u in java this will not work:     class Copy
{
 int x,y;
 Copy(int x,int y)
 {
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
 }
 void show()
 {
  System.out.println(x);
  System.out.println(y);
 }
    Copy(Copy z)
 {
  this.x=z.x;
  this.y=z.y;
 }
 public static void main(String... s)
 {
  Copy c1=new Copy(10,20);
  c1.show();
  Copy c2=new Copy(c1);
  c2.show();
 }
}

Comment: @sagg1295 please have a look at your comment. In its current form it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @sagg1295 I am saying the question doesn't make sense because it doesn't apply in Java. There is no Object or struct variable types and thus no copy constructor. (Yet Java 10 might have them)

Comment: @sagg1295 `Copy(Copy z) { this.x=z.x; this.y=z.y; }` can be seen as some kind of copy constructor (although not in the way C++ uses them) and this is possible. Additionally, as I already mentioned, there is no recursion involved. You pass the reference `z` to the constructor and use that to access the values `x` and `y` of the referenced object (and because it is a reference - and could even be called a pointer - it can be null).

Comment: @sagg1295 I have updated my answer to say you can do something like a copy constructor but it must be called explicitly, as there is no language support for it implicitly.  There is no risk of recursion.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, you forgot to mention it causes StackOverflowError :-)

Comment: @JavaHopper If there was recursion, you would get a StackOverflow, but there isn't.

Comment: @PeterLawrey its infinite recursion, is it not? Which would ultimately terminate in StackOverflowError

Comment: @JavaHopper What recursion, infinite or otherwise, are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Java copy constructor for any object is a deep copy of this object. 
For example,

```
 public Car(String motorShow, double price) {
     this.motorShow = motorShow;
     this.price = price;
 }  ^ ordinary constructor for a Car object


//the copy constructor for Car:
  public Car(Car other) {
    this.motorShow = other.motorShow;
    this.price = price;
  }   
/* Simply in the main class write Car c2 = new Car(c1);    

 this basically will create a copy of c1 of, and note that changing the attributes of one of the objects won't affect the other since it's a deep copy; unlike this for example:
 Car c1 = c2;
 here, changing any attribute of c1 or c2 will affect the other, i.e two pointers for the same space or reference in memory  */
```

I hope this helps.